# Como disparar uma função JS dentro de um IF PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Dentro do PHP tem um IF que deve executar uma função JS.

Assim:

```
if ($x == $y) {
    // como executar a função nada() dentro deste if?
}

?>

<script>

function nada() {

    alert("nada de mais");

}
</script>
```

Resumindo, de acordo com um valor obtido do banco de dados, a função JS é ou não executada. Por que assim não roda?

Imagino que possa ter algo a ver com Ajax / JSON. Seria isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode chamar a função através de um `echo`:

```
<?php
if ($x == $y) {
    echo '<script>
    window.onload = function(){ nada(); };
    </script>';
}
?>

<script>
function nada() {

    alert("nada de mais");

}
</script>
```

Se o script for carregado antes do `echo`, o `window.onload` é opcional:

```
<script>
function nada() {

    alert("nada de mais");

}
</script>

<?php
if ($x == $y) {
    echo '<script> nada(); </script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria.. não faça isso. Mas de qualquer forma.

```
<?php if(foo): ?>
    <script> bar() </script> 
<?php endif; ?>


<script> function bar() { /*do something...*/ } </script>
```